# c# ClickOnce URL parameter always same value

Tags: c#, clickonce

I am using this way to get the URL parameter from my click one application.

However, i always get back the first time value i pass to the application even i had change the pass in value in the sub sequence time. Do i need any setting on web server ?

below are my code.

```
public static NameValueCollection GetQueryStringParameters()
{
    NameValueCollection nameValueTable = new NameValueCollection();
    if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
    {
        string queryString = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdateLocation.Query; 
        nameValueTable = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
    }

return (nameValueTable);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why use `UpdateLocation.Query`? I think you need to change it to [`ActivationUri.Query`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.activationuri(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Which Gets the URL used to launch the deployment manifest of the application.